# Adding not selector to style breaks styling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a certain `hover` style to all element **except** the first. For some odd reason `:first-child` works, but adding `:not(first-child)` doesn't. Why? Full JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/45xmsybw/1/).

EDIT:
Apparently a small addition of code breaks this style, something I didn't add to the original fiddle because I didn't think It would matter, now I realise it does. Please note that the style does not work when additional tags are located between the `a` tags, like so:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div id="logoContainer">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_white.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Working CSS:

```
.sidenav a:first-child:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Not working at all CSS:

```
.sidenav a:not:(first-child):hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your selector, not is written as `:not()`

Comment: its `:not(:first-child)` instead of `:not:(first-child)` (notice the location of the second double colon)

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working

Comment: @TylerH: Out of close votes for the day?

Comment: @BoltClock Used a different cv reason before I read the comments about fixing the typo not working.

Comment: @TylerH: Fair enough. Here, lemme help.

Comment: In my original code there are several more tags before the `a` tags, that breaks the styling. Please take a look and reopen the question.

Comment: @undroid do you want the x to be red on hover as well? e.g. you only want the logo to not change on hover?

Comment: @TylerH I dont want the X to be styled upon hover.

Comment: @undroid OK, that's where the confusion is. That's not actually your first `a` element. One minute.

Comment: @undroid You can also use sibling selector see my answer below, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This utilizes a combination of the `:not` pseudo-selector and the direct descendant selector to apply styles only to `<a>` elements that are *immediate*, or *direct*, descendants of `.sidenav`.

Since your first `<a>` element is a grand-child, and not a direct child, of `.sidenav`, it doesn't get the `color: red` styling thanks to `>`, and since your close 'x' has a class of `closebtn`, we can use `:not(.closebtn)` to eliminate that one from getting red styling, as well:

```css
.sidenav > a:not(.closebtn):hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <div id="logoContainer">
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <img src="assets/img/logo_white.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my fiddle and it still not working right: please take a look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cnnwepvz/

Comment: @undroid Updated my answer to not color the 'x' **or** the logo on hover.

Comment: This - `.sidenav > a:not(.closebtn):hover` should also work and if the markup remains same then it would be more simpler :) (*Not saying that your answer is incorrect*)

Comment: @TylerH: Nope, it shouldn't because it is not a child of `.sidenav`.

Comment: @Harry Oh, I see I was missing the `>` in your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Could you please explain what I was missing? edit- just saw you added an explanation. many thanks.

Comment: @undroid I think it was confusing you because, while your x was the first element that appears on the page, it wasn't the first element in your HTML code, so you were actually targeting the logo rather than `<a class="closebtn">`

Comment: Silly me. I finally get it. Thanks for that extra explanation.

Comment: The fiddle in my answer does the same thing, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ovokuro See the update to the question. OP has more code before the first `<a>`

Comment: Ah ok, just saw that.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks slightly wrong.
Try:

```
.sidenav a:not(:first-child):hover{
    color: red;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45xmsybw/)

Comment: Just missed out. Thought I would be the first here

Comment: it was close :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of direct children `>` and next sibling `+` selectors.

```css
.sidenav > a + a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div id="logoContainer">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_white.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
.sidenav a:not(:first-child):hover{
    color: red;
}
```